# Can I build a mitered aluminum glass frame from glass edge banding?

Tags: windows

Can I build a more substantial window frame from ultra thin aluminum edge banding by mitering the corners and installing a super low profile corner key?

Comment: More substantial than what? Where are you using this window? There are usually code requirements to meet...

Comment: @freeman Stronger at the corners than just gluing the mitered edge frame to the glass.  Something that will transmit forces applied from the clips pressing on the aluminum banding to the whole length of banding and through the corner, not forcing the last inch of glass at the corner to take the load.  Creating a FRAME around the glass. But ultra thin, with a super low profile channel for the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe as to structure can be built if you have:

1. A source for the aluminum extrusion frame material. If no source you may need to design its cross section profile yourself and then finance a manufacturer to extrude the material for you.
2. A source for the corner brace piece. For a custom designed extrusion you would need to design around some existing corner or design and get custom corner pieces stamped out. Be prepared for a tooling charge for custom parts.
3. The tools needed to cut the aluminum extrusions and a press to push in the corner brackets. Depending upon the method used to retain the corner pieces you may also need  a tool to crimp or rivet the part in place.
4. Patience to put it together with the glass panels.

What is not at all certain is if this will provide the protection against glass breakage and shattering that you desire. Obviously the design of the frame will need a good bit of engineering modeling to fully understand the rigidity and strength of the frame to protect the glass. It is almost assured the slimmer, thinner and lower profile the frame the less protection it will offer to the glass. There will also be considerations on the type of glass used, its panel size and thickness.

Another factor that also plays into the protection level is if the frame will include a rubber or vinyl isolation strip between the frame and the glass. This alone will likely require considerable engineering work and experimentation.

Comment: Thorough, informed, incisive, elucidating, and apparently correct.  Do you happen to have a dozen removable glazing panels for an Andersen 2817 basement hopper window?

Comment: @AndyzSmith - Why would you think I would have those specific windows?

Comment: @AndyzSmith - Maybe you can find them here: https://parts.andersenwindows.com/search.jsp?fs_0_UnitNumberandSize=2817&category=w_basement

Comment: Yeah i have that site, and 0240816 is the exact match hopper sash, BUT the replacement sash unit doesnt come with the options (the removable glazing) that were offered on new installation.